# Is it possible to build daemon apps to access outlook.com mails or calendars?

Tags: authentication, outlook, daemon, office365api

I managed to create client credential grant daemon app to access office 365 or microsoft graph. Thanks to this blog (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tsmatsuz/2016/10/07/application-permission-with-v2-endpoint-and-microsoft-graph/)

I have also been able to create auth code grant web app to access office 365 or outlook. Thanks to this blog (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/richard_dizeregas_blog/2015/09/04/working-with-the-converged-azure-ad-v2-app-model/)

Now I have a question. Is it possible to create a daemon application to access outlook.com resources?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm looking for the same. Did you ever find an answer?